# Calculating and displaying score statistics using C# 6.0 features

Tags: c#, beginner, array, statistics

I'm studying C# and trying to work on efficiency and making the best use of C# 6.0 features. I have created the following program based on an exercise challenge in a book, and have used Resharper to fix certain things; however, I still feel my novice knowledge of C# is preventing me from creating the below program in a more efficient manner, and I'm wondering if there are any glaring changes I could make to produce a cleaner set of code that Resharper isn't pointing out.

The objective was intentionally to use Jagged Arrays, and I do know I could've just used lists and made things easier; so, please don't recommend replacing the array/jagged arrays with a list.

```
    static readonly string[] Files = { @"C:\Section1.txt",
                                       @"C:Section2.txt",
                                       @"C:\Section3.txt"};

    readonly Dictionary<string, int> _myfiles = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    internal int[][] JaggedArray = new int[Files.Length][];
    int _minV;
    int _maxV;
    string _minS = "";
    string _maxS = "";

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Get_File_Counts();
        Insert_Into_JA();
        Display_Results();
    }

    private void Get_File_Counts()
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Files.Length; i++)
        {
            var read = new StreamReader(Files[i]);
            var counter = 0;
            while (read.ReadLine() != null)
            {
                counter++;
            }
            _myfiles[$"Sec{i+1}"] = counter;
            read.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Insert_Into_JA()
    {
        for (var x = 0; x < Files.Length; x++)
        {
            var read = new StreamReader(Files[x]);
            string tline;
            var tempArray = new int[_myfiles[$"Sec{x + 1}"]];
            var i = 0;
            while ((tline = read.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var line = int.Parse(tline);

                if (_minV == 0 || line < _minV)
                {
                    _minV = line;
                    _minS = $"Sec {(x + 1)}";
                }
                else if ((line == _minV) && (_minS != $"Sec {(x + 1)}"))
                {
                    _minS = $"{_minS} & Sec {(x + 1)}";
                }
                if (_maxV == 0 || line > _maxV)
                {
                    _maxV = line;
                    _maxS = $"Sec {(x + 1)}";
                }
                else if ((line == _maxV) && (_maxS != $"Sec {(x + 1)}"))
                {
                    _maxS = $"{_maxS} & Sec {(x + 1)}";
                }
                tempArray[i] = line;
                i++;
                switch (x)
                {
                    case 0:
                        Scores1.Items.Add(line);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Scores2.Items.Add(line);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Scores3.Items.Add(line);
                        break;
                }
            }
            JaggedArray[x] = tempArray;
            read.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Display_Results()
    {
        for (var x = 0;x<Files.Length;x++)
        {
            double total = 0;
            var tscores = _myfiles[$"Sec{x + 1}"];
            for (var i = 0;i<tscores;i++)
            {
                total += JaggedArray[x][i];
            }
            switch (x)
            {
                case 0:
                    Sec1Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Sec2Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Sec3Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
                    break;
            }
        }
        TAvg.Text = ((double.Parse(Sec1Avg.Text) + double.Parse(Sec2Avg.Text) + double.Parse(Sec3Avg.Text)) / 3).ToString("n2");
        THScore.Text = $"{_maxV}, {_maxS}";
        TLScore.Text = $"{_minV}, {_minS}";
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I prefer to use explicit access modifiers -- it keeps everything uniform: you have `internal int[][] JaggedArray` so I'd make the others like `_minV` explicitly `private`.

---

Every field that is outside-world accessible, should be a property. This means `internal`, `protected internal` and `public` fields. The benefit of this is that you can always decide later to add validation logic without breaking your contract.

This is commonly known as [encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)).

---

Some people (like me) prefer to use `string.Empty` instead of `""` because the intentions are perceived unambiguously whereas `""` always nags at me saying it might be a typo.

---

Conventions dictate that no underscores are used: methods are `UpperCamelCase`. The event handler might be an exception due to its widespread default usage although I would instead opt for a `OnButtonClicked` pattern.

---

Instead of explicitly closing your `StreamReader`, consider wrapping it in a [using statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) instead.

---

Instead of

```
var read = new StreamReader(Files[i]);
var counter = 0;
while (read.ReadLine() != null)
{
    counter++;
}
_myfiles[$"Sec{i + 1}"] = counter;
read.Close();
```

you could do

```
_myfiles[$"Sec{i + 1}"] = File.ReadLines(Files[i]).Count;
```

---

Why are you storing the keys as `Sec{i}`? I think it would be easier if you simply addressed them as `i` -- that way you don't have these curious string interpolations throughout your code.

---

Consider also using more descriptive names: `tLine`, `tempArray`, `JaggedArray`, `_minV`, etc. don't say much about their purpose.

---

```
var line = int.Parse(tline);
```

This can throw an exception which you should consider either catching or using `int.TryParse()`.

If the input is expected to contain invalid data and you're throwing on purpose, then it might be useful to document in what scenarios it could have that invalid input.

---

```
for (var x = 0; x < Files.Length; x++)
{
    double total = 0;
    var tscores = _myfiles[$"Sec{x + 1}"];
    for (var i = 0; i < tscores; i++)
    {
        total += JaggedArray[x][i];
    }
    switch (x)
    {
        case 0:
            Sec1Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
            break;
        case 1:
            Sec2Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
            break;
        case 2:
            Sec3Avg.Text = (total / tscores).ToString("n2");
            break;
    }
}
```

This is an ugly usage of a `switch` and prone to errors (you can easily forget another case when you add a 4th file).

I would consider slightly rewriting it with a method to help you:

```
private double GetTotal(int fileIndex, int scoreAmount)
{
    var total = 0.0;
    for (var i = 0; i < scoreAmount; i++)
    {
        total += JaggedArray[x][i];
    }

    return total;
}

var sec1Scores = _myFiles[x + 1];
Sec1Avg.Text = (GetTotal(0, sec1Score) / sec1Scores).ToString("n2");

var sec2Scores = _myFiles[x + 1];
Sec2Avg.Text = (GetTotal(1, sec1Score) / sec2Scores).ToString("n2");

var sec3Scores = _myFiles[x + 1];
Sec3Avg.Text = (GetTotal(2, sec1Score) / sec3Scores).ToString("n2");
```

At this point you could decide to continue rewriting this but that's up to you.

---

```
TAvg.Text = ((double.Parse(Sec1Avg.Text) + double.Parse(Sec2Avg.Text) + double.Parse(Sec3Avg.Text)) / 3).ToString("n2");
```

First you calculate everything, then you round it, then you parse and then you round it again. This is bound to lose accuracy.

Comment: +1. I find people use the term PascalCase more often than UpperCamelCase though (but both are correct)

Comment: Outstanding. This is exactly the kind of information I was looking for. Thank you so much for your feedback. I will add that it being dynamic was a concern. I really wanted to figure out how to make the code adaptable in the event there were more than 4 sections, like dynamically adding new list boxes in that case. The reason I wanted to make them like Sec{i} was originally because I thought I could compare a function as a string. So, somehow, rather than using that switch to determine which file I was on, have it know to add to the new list box and such when it hit the End of Stream.